# x86 Data Type (0x) Assistance

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

what is meant when 0x leads a number? Is it some sort of special data type or memory address?

Take for example this line:

add eax,0x77

I am unsure what the 0x is place in-front of the 77 for could anyone please clarify?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with x86 but I'd assume 0x indicates it's hex (base-16 number).

Comment: @FoolishSeth cheers may be a good point in the right direction , will check it out on Google further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a C/C++ way to express hexadecimal constants. In assemblers you usually write `12H` and `0FH` for the same thing as `0x12` and `0xF` in C and C++. Some assemblers support this syntax as well (e.g. `NASM`).

Comment: Okay thanks a bunch!! I was actually writing this in visual studio inline with C++ so makes a lot of sense. Just isn't much easy to find info on x86 out there